# How to play AVI files on MacBook Pro

Tags: file, disk-format

Using GoPro software, I had imported videos to PC. However when I bought a new macbook pro, I transferred all files onto an external Hard Drive. They are currently in .avi format. I am struggling to play the video files on the MacBook, as the file type is not supported.

How can i play `.avi` files ?

Comment: Use (download) the VLC player.

Answer (score 6):

[VideoLAN's VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) is the way to go here, I haven't found a movie file that it can't play.

Answer (score 1):

You could, also, convert them to mp4/m4v using [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr), which is free.